# Iniciar a leitura do começo da string list

Tags: java, array, string

Como faço para após adicionar uma string em uma lista (pode ser na lista A ou B), o meu código volte e comece a leitura do inicio da string `list`, ou seja da primeira string?

Eu tenho uma lista com 20 strings. Mas ta dando um erro porque o meu código adiciona a `string` e segue para a próxima posição. Ele não volta e começa a leitura do início. Assim tem strings que não são adicionadas.

Como faço para após adicionar uma string, o meu código volte e comece a leitura do inicio (posição 0 da string list), ou seja da primeira string?

Alguém pode me passar um exemplo? Estou quebrando a cabeça com isso e não saio do lugar.

```
 public int calcFitness(int indv) {

    String linha1 = individualID.get(indv);     
    String[] taskQe = linha1.split(" ");
    String linha2 = individualDep.get(indv);    
    String[] depQe = linha2.split(" "); 
    String linha3 = individualHour.get(indv);
    String[] hourQe = linha3.split(" ");
    String linha4 = individualEmpl.get(indv);
    String[] emplQe = linha4.split(" ");    
    int fitness=0;


     for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < taskQe.length; taskIndex++) {
        String currentTask = taskQe[taskIndex];
        String currentDep = depQe[taskIndex];
        String currentHour = hourQe[taskIndex];
        System.out.println("task: [" + currentTask + "], dep: [" + currentDep + "], hours: [" + currentHour + "]");

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(currentHour);

        if (currentDep.equals("0")) {
        //  System.out.println ("axhou 0");
            if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {
                Cp1.add(currentTask);
                Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp1TotalHours += hour;   

            } else {
                Cp2.add(currentTask);
                Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp2TotalHours += hour;

            }

        }

            else  if (Cp1.contains(currentDep) || Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
            //System.out.println ("achou dep" + currentDep );
                for (int i=0; i<=taskIndex; i++) {
                if (depQe[i].equals(currentDep)){
                System.out.println ("achou dep i and curr" + (taskQe[i]) + currentDep );
                if ((Cp1.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours))){
                    Cp1.add(taskQe[i]);
                    Cp1Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                    Cp1Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                    Cp1TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));

                        }
                        else if ((Cp2.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp2TotalHours < Cp1TotalHours))){
                            Cp2.add(taskQe[i]);
                            Cp2Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                            Cp2Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                            Cp2TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));   
                        }

                        else if ((!Cp1.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours))){   
                               idle = Math.abs(Cp2TotalHours  - Cp1TotalHours );
                               Cp1TotalHours=+idle;
                               if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours){
                                   Cp1.add(taskQe[i]);
                                   Cp1Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                                   Cp1Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                                   Cp1TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));

                               }
                               else{
                                Cp2.add(taskQe[i]);
                                Cp2Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                                Cp2Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                                Cp2TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])); 

                               }

                /*  for (int j=0; j<taskQe.length; j++) {   
                       if(depQe[i].equals(taskQe[j]))
                           idle = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]) - (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])));
                           Cp1TotalHours=+idle;
                    }*/
                }
                else if ((!Cp2.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp2TotalHours < Cp1TotalHours))){
                    idle = Math.abs(Cp2TotalHours  - Cp1TotalHours );
                    Cp2TotalHours=+idle;
                    if (Cp2TotalHours < Cp1TotalHours){
                    Cp2.add(taskQe[i]);
                    Cp2Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                    Cp2Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                    Cp2TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])); 

                    }
                    else{
                           Cp1.add(taskQe[i]);
                           Cp1Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                           Cp1Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                           Cp1TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));  

                    }

                /*   for (int j=0; j<taskQe.length; j++) {  
                    if(depQe[i].equals(taskQe[j]))
                            idle = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]) - (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])));
                            Cp2TotalHours=+idle;
                        }*/

                        }

                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem? Tem como colocar seu código?

Comment: @PauloCosta eu esto usando java. Vou postar o meu código na descrição da pergunta. Eu tenho 20 strings, mas o meu código só adiciona 13.

Comment: Quando vc inserir não poderia colocar o indice = 0?

Comment: Fiz isso @Marconi, but dai fica num loop.

Comment: @Jsi83 Provavelmente está entrando em um loop ao setar o índice para zero porque sua lógica deve estar com algum problema. Deve estar sempre caindo na situação em que o índice é setado para zero. Você precisa garantir que em algum momento o índice não será setado para zero e o loop irá encerrar. Se puder, poste qual é o problema que você está tentando resolver. Não entendi muito bem o que você está fazendo. Dessa forma eu vou poder testar o código e te ajudar a achar a solução.